# Table inside description list

Tags: tables, floats, lists, description

I'm trying to put a table inside a list environment but without success. I'd like to have the table inside the item (matching `\linewidth`) and not floating in the next page.

```
\begin{description}
    \item[Lorem ipsum] \hfill \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    \item[Lorem ipsum] \hfill \\
        \begin{table}[h]
            \centering
            \caption{Foobar}
            \label{tab:foobar}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
                \toprule
                \textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\
                \midrule
                Lorem ipsum & foo \\
                Lorem ipsum & bar \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{description}
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Remove the `table` environment.

Comment: Well, it is difficulty to help you without the code to produce the error. Also if there is no space enough to insert the table, no way, it will be inserted after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to leave the `table` as is, inside the `description` environment, you can avoid it to float simply replacing the floating specifier `h` with the `H` provided by the the `float` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float} % defines the H specifier

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[Lorem ipsum] \hfill \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    \item[Lorem ipsum] \hfill \\
        \begin{table}[H]
            \centering
            \caption{Foobar}
            \label{tab:foobar}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
                \toprule
                \textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\
                \midrule
                Lorem ipsum & foo \\
                Lorem ipsum & bar \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The specifier `H` did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want table to float. Then remove the `table` environment. You can have the caption with the help of `\captionof` macro from either `caption` or `capt-of` packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of,booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
    \item[Lorem ipsum] \hfill \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    \item[Lorem ipsum] \hfill \\
            \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \captionof{table}{Foobar}
            \label{tab:foobar}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
                \toprule
                \textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\
                \midrule
                Lorem ipsum & foo \\
                Lorem ipsum & bar \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried your method before and it has some faults: caption is not aligned with the table; can't control table width; vertical space between caption and the table is non existent.

Comment: @RenatoRodrigues My method works too ;) See the edited answer.